# JQuery AJAX request not working.

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using AJAX for the first time and I am not sure if I have the correct syntax down. Basically I have a method in the behind code that takes in 2 string parameters and executes an updates the users password. But it keeps coming back as failed.

Here is my current asp button:

```
<td><asp:Button  ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Password" alt="Add Password" /></td>
```

This is the code that executes once the user hits the Add Password button on the form:

```
$("#edit_password_form").submit(function (e) {
                         e.preventDefault();

                         var finalValue = value2.value;

                         <%string inputCust = Session[SessionKey.CUSTOMER_ID].ToString();%>
                         var custNoString = <%=inputCust%>

                         $.ajax({
                             url: 'reciept.aspx/Button1_Click',
                             method: 'post',
                             contentType: 'application/json',
                             data: '{custID:' + custNoString + 'tempPass2:' + finalValue + '}',
                             success: function(){

                                 alert("The function worked correctly");

                             },
                             error:function(){ alert("the function did not succeed");}
                         });
                     });;
```

Any ideas on why it could be failing? Mayb I am missing an ajax key or my syntax could be off.

Let me know! Thanks.

Comment: Try not passing your data as a string but instead as an object. `data: { custID: custNoString, tempPass2: finalValue }`.

Comment: side note:  consider using a regular button instead of a submit button.  Call your function on the button click event.  This will allow you to get rid of `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data parameters need properly created `JSON`.  You are missing out on some single quotes here and there.

Instead of manually creating the `JSON` string, try creating an object first, then stringify it for data. Refer to the code below:

```
 $("#edit_password_form").submit(function (e) {
                         e.preventDefault();

                         var finalValue = value2.value;

                         <%string inputCust = Session[SessionKey.CUSTOMER_ID].ToString();%>
                         var custNoString = <%=inputCust%>

                         var dataObj = {};
                         dataObj.custID = custNoString;
                         dataObj.tempPass2 = finalValue;

                         $.ajax({
                             url: 'reciept.aspx/Button1_Click',
                             method: 'post',
                             contentType: 'application/json',
                             data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
                             success: function(){

                                 alert("The function worked correctly");

                             },
                             error:function(){ alert("the function did not succeed");}
                         });
                     });;
```

Comment: Ok I added the data  data: JSON.stringify({custID1: dataObj.custID1, tempPass2: dataObj.tempPass2}) like this, would this be correct?

Answer (score 1):

it is not correct syntax to post data:   `data: '{custID:' + custNoString + 'tempPass2:' + finalValue + '}'`

try to pass your data by json format this way  `data: { custID: custNoString, tempPass2: finalValue }`

otherwise it should not work .

more check this link http://www.json.org/JSONRequest.html

Comment: Nazmul, do I need to use apostrophes in the json format way?

Comment: must be to get best afford

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted as answer on behalf of the OP)*.

This is what ended up working for me:

```
 // Create the data object for the 2 parameters for the c# Method

                     var dataObj = { custID1: custNoString, tempPass2: finalValue };



                     // AJAX request for run the function

                     $.ajax({

                         type: 'post',

                         url: 'reciept.aspx/Button1_Click',

                         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

                         data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),

                         success: function(){



                            alert("The function worked correctly");

                         },

                         error:function(){ alert("the function did not succeed");} 

                     });
```

Creating the data object first was the key. Thank you for all your help and suggestions!